# Fetching records from MySQL database with PHP to populate a drop down list

Tags: php, mysql

im having trouble with my code. I'm trying to populate a drop down list from my database but the list is showing empty space instead of database entries. I would be very grateful if anyone could help me.

```
<?php
include("db_config.php");
$sql="SELECT * FROM brojevi";
$result=mysqli_query($connection,$sql);
echo "<select name=\"id\" size=\"1\">";
echo "<option value=\"choose\">-choose-</option>";
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
unset($id,$broj);
$id=$row['id'];
$broj=$row['brojevi'];
echo "<option value=\"$id\">$broj</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
?>
```

Here is the table( its a simple one cause im just making this for practice )

```
 CREATE TABLE `brojevi` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
 `broj` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
 );

INSERT INTO `brojevi` (`id`, `broj`) VALUES
(1, 1),
(2, 2);
```

Comment: You should look into the [MVC Design Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller).

Comment: How does the table look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are messing up your single and double quotes. Try this:

```
<?php
include("db_config.php");
$sql="SELECT * FROM brojevi";
$result=mysqli_query($connection,$sql);
echo '<select name="dropdown" size="1">';
echo '<option value="choose">-choose-</option>';
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $id = $row['id'];
    $broj = $row['brojevi'];
    echo '<option value="' . $id . '">' . $broj . '</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
?>
```

When using html tags inside your echo, try to use single quotes for the echo and double quotes for html stuff like values,id's,classes etc.